# getText() method returns all the values in dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, gettext

I'm working with the below HTML:

```
Select a number:
<select onchange="updatesum()" name="s1">
<option selected="">0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4 </option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9 </option>
</select>
```

I want to select any number from this HTML(which contains numbers in String format), assign it to an `int` variable.

The approach I used is:

1. Create a WebElement and select the desired value from this WebElement.
2. Using getText(), assign it's value to a String variable.
3. Convert into an int and assign it to the int variable.

The below code for above 2 steps is as follows.

```
        WebElement drop = dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@name='s1']"));
        Select num1 = new Select(drop);
        num1.selectByIndex(2);
        String val1 = dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@name='s1']")).getText();
```

When I run this, it returns all the values in the dropdown, because of which I cannot convert it into int. I require only the selected value to be returned by `getText()`.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`getFirstSelectOption()` method](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#getFirstSelectedOption--):

```
String val1 = num1.getFirstSelectOption().getText();
```